# SIGKILL init process (PID 1)

Tags: unix, signals, init, pid, sigkill

I'm facing a weird issue regarding sending signal 9 (SIGKILL) to the init process (PID 1).
As you may know, SIGKILL can't be ignored via signal handlers. As I tried sending SIGKILL to init, I noticed that nothing was happening; init would not get terminated. Trying to figure out this behaviour, I decided to attach myself to the init process with strace too see more clearly what was happening. Now comes the weird part. If I'm "looking" at the init process with strace and send it SIGKILL, the system crashes.

My question is why is this happening? Why does the system crash when I look at the process and why does it not crash when I'm not? As I said, in both cases I send SIGKILL to init. Tested on CentOS 6.5, Debian 7 and Arch.

Thanks!

Comment: Without `init`, I don't think you have a functioning operating system. If you want to kill `init`, you could just as well shutdown/halt/poweroff.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but my "experiment" was out of pure curiosity.

Comment: You're right, it's kinda fun.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Linux kernel deliberately forces a system crash if `init` terminates (see http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/exit.c?v=3.12#L501 and particularly the call to `panic` therein).  Therefore, as a safeguard, the kernel will not deliver *any* fatal signal to `init`, and `SIGKILL` is not excepted (see http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.12&i=SIGNAL_UNKILLABLE) (however, the code flow is convoluted enough that I'm not sure, but I *suspect* a kernel-generated `SIGSEGV` or similar would go through).

Applying [`ptrace(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) (the system call that `strace` uses) to process 1 apparently disables this protection.  This could be said to be a bug in the kernel.  I am insufficiently skilled at digging around in the code to find this bug.

I do not know if other Unix variants apply the same crash-on-exit semantics or signal protection to `init`.  It would be reasonable to have the OS perform a clean shutdown or reboot, rather than a panic, if `init` terminates (at least, if it does so by calling `_exit`) but as far as I know, all modern Unix variants have a dedicated system call to request this, instead ([`reboot(2)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=reboot&sektion=2)).

Comment: BTW, On Debian 7, SIGSEGV doesn't crash the init. On Arch and CentOS, it does.

Comment: I'm afraid "Debian 7", "Arch", and "CentOS" all refer to such large bundles of diverse software of uncertain age that this is useless as a data point.  Also, if you tried `kill -SEGV 1`, that tells you nothing about what happens for *kernel-generated* SIGSEGV, e.g. if `init` actually attempts to dereference an invalid pointer.