# Getting the id of a Parent Process from its child in C

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork

I am a computer science student , i am curently taking a operating systems course that requires us to work with C 
one question that i am trying to solve is the following :

Write a program that forks a child.

The child should sleep for 5 sec.

The child should print “I am ready to murder my parent!”

The child should kill its parent via a signal(use kill(parent_id,SIGINT)).

The child should print “I am an orphan now”.

The parent should wait for the child and print “I am the parent”.

i have tried to solve it using the following code , but i wasnt able to find a way to get the parent's id .any help is appreciated , thanks in advance :)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>


int main ()
{
  pid_t pid =fork();


  if (pid<0)
    {
      printf("%s\n","Error in forking");
    }

  else if (pid==0)//child
    {
      sleep(5);
      printf("%s","I am ready to murder my parent!");
       kill(//parent id here,SIGINT);
      printf("%s","I am an orphan now");


    }
  else{ // parent

    printf("%s\n","I am the parent");



  }
  return 0;



}
```

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/getppid

Comment: getppid in the child ?

Comment: Just call getpid() before you call fork() and you'll get it handed to you on a silver platter.

Comment: @HansPassant Thats neat.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Haris mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33264151/4042839), You should use [getppid()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getppid) to get the `pid` of the parent.

---

In response to your comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264100/getting-the-id-of-a-parent-process-from-its-child-in-c#comment54329930_33264151),

> well i tried it , and lol that might seems funny , but my program killed my os , my linux machine shuted down

Let's have a look at your code,

```
else if (pid==0){ //child
        sleep(5);
        printf("%s","I am ready to murder my parent!");
        kill(//parent id here,SIGINT);
        printf("%s","I am an orphan now");
}
else{ // parent
        printf("%s\n","I am the parent");
}
```

What will the parent process do after it finishes executing `printf("%s\n","I am the parent");` ? It terminates.

So, who is the parent of a process whose original parent has terminated ? The child process becomes an orphan. Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process)

> An orphan process is a computer process whose parent process has finished or terminated, though it remains running itself. In a Unix-like operating system any orphaned process will be immediately adopted by the special init system process.

Therefore, when you are invoking `kill()` you are doing so on the `init` process. This is the reason for `lol that might seems funny , but my program killed my os , my linux machine shuted down`

Do have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21031583/4042839).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [`getppid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getppid.html)

> getppid() returns the process ID of the parent of the calling process.

Comment: well i tried it , and lol that might seems funny , but my program killed my os , my linux machine shuted down

Comment: It's a bit hard to believe that you could kill it. But if that happened is cause parent pid was 1 (The init process in linux). Are you sure you did it in the child process?

Comment: @CaptainZi That is happening because your parent process is completed even before you call `kill` on it. I'll post a detailed answer in sometime if you are not able to figure it out.

Comment: so i guess i should wait in the parent process